# Android push notification from php server

Tags: php, android, websocket

The scenario is I just want to send push notification from from php server to Android device what is exactly done by GCM AND FCM but I don't want to use these services and I want to try this using php web sockets , is it possible? And how to implement this ? Thanks

Comment: Any reason behind not using FCM?

Comment: i just want to implement on my own :)

Comment: Use socket.io then might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tools out there for websockets in php like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) and [Wrench](https://github.com/varspool/Wrench).

But there are many features that FCM does provide and not built in these libraries, So check your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet for php is php Ratchet.
Ratchet is a loosely coupled PHP library providing developers with tools to create real time, bi-directional applications between clients and servers over WebSockets.

Here is a great tutorial to get you started.
https://blog.samuelattard.com/the-tutorial-for-php-websockets-that-i-wish-had-existed/